# Python KeyError when Comparing two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have extracted data from a CSV file and want to use it update values in a spreadsheet.  The dataframe has a column 'ticker' of values.  I want to check the existing values in the spreadsheet, and if the CSV has a new value add the new value to the spreadsheet.

```
if df_xls.empty:
    df_xls = df_xls.append(pd.DataFrame({"ticker": [[reduced.ticker[0]]]}), ignore_index=True)
wtw = 1

print(reduced.columns.values)
print(df_xls.columns.values)

for csv_row in reduced:
    for xls_row in df_xls:
        if reduced.ticker[csv_row] == df_xls.ticker[xls_row]:
            wtw = 0
            break
        else:
            next(xls_row)
if wtw == 1:
     df_xls = df_xls.append(pd.DataFrame({"ticker": [[reduced.ticker[csv_row]]]}), ignore_index=True)
next(csv_row)
```

I am getting a "KeyError: 'ticker'" in reference to the line "if reduced.ticker[csv_row] == df_xls.ticker[xls_row]:"  I don't understand the error given the column names are correct.  The print outputs above display:

```
['ticker' '2021-02-01 shares' '2021-02-01 value']
['ticker']
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit --

I do not have the code available at a URL, but here is the entirety of the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = "2021-02-01-FULLREPORT.csv"

##load new information from CSV into dataframe##
df_csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
prefix = filename[0:10]

ticker = df_csv.ticker
shares = df_csv.shares
value = df_csv["market value($)"]

reduced = pd.DataFrame({
    "ticker": ticker,
    prefix +" shares": shares,
    prefix +" value": value
})
##end load new information from CSV into dataframe##

##load excel
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
df_xls = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

##update ticker list with information saved in reduced##

if df_xls.empty:
    df_xls = df_xls.append(pd.DataFrame({"ticker": [[reduced.ticker[0]]]}), ignore_index=True)
wtw = 1

print(reduced.columns.values)
print(df_xls.columns.values)

for csv_row in reduced:
    for xls_row in df_xls:
        if reduced.ticker[csv_row] == df_xls.ticker[xls_row]:
            wtw = 0
            break
        else:
            next(xls_row)
if wtw == 1:
     df_xls = df_xls.append(pd.DataFrame({"ticker": [[reduced.ticker[csv_row]]]}), ignore_index=True)
next(csv_row)

print (df_xls)
```

This resolved the KeyError:

```
##load excel
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
df_xls = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

##update ticker list saved in reduced##

for csv_row in reduced.index:
    wtw = 1
    print ("testing " + reduced.ticker[csv_row])
    for xls_row in df_xls.index:
        print ("comparing "+ reduced.ticker[csv_row] + "with ")
        print (df_xls.ticker[xls_row])
        if reduced.ticker[csv_row] == df_xls.ticker[xls_row]:
            print ("match found")
            wtw = 0
            break
    if wtw == 1:
        df_xls = df_xls.append(pd.DataFrame({"ticker": [[reduced.ticker[csv_row]]]}), ignore_index=True)

print (df_xls)
```

Comment: Can you please give URL to see your code

Comment: It might be that `df_xls` cannot reach ticker that way, can you try  `if reduced.ticker[csv_row] == df_xls['ticker'][xls_row]:`? Let me know if that works, I will put it in an answer for you to accept :)

Comment: @Suman I do not have a URL but have updated the post with the full script.

Comment: @JarroVGIT `if reduced.ticker[csv_row] == df_xls['ticker'][xls_row]:` did not make a difference in the output.

Comment: @chanie please provide csv & excel file to us

Comment: @Suman they can be downloaded [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e5550399f42a5d8d8aec9e3ab4398f6d20210205025709/3ece52)

Comment: @chanie what you want in your code?

Comment: @Suman sorry, I'm not understand the question.  my goal was to update the "ticker" list in XLS with new occurrences from the "ticket" list in CVS.  Starting with the first row from CVS, the intent was to proceed over each row of XLS.  If a match was found, then to move on to the next row of CVS and restart the comparison.  If the last row of XLS was reached without a match, then to add the value from CVS to the XLS list. on the first instance, given the files I provided, all values will be new, but in subsequent usage that would not be the case.

Comment: @chanie should we do call so better understand

Comment: i believe the issue was failing to include ".index" after the references to the dataframes.  i've edited the original with the new code that resolves the KeyError (but there are other flaws with it that i will not go into here)